# zero vector in the existence of additive inverse axiom of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, axioms

In the axioms of vector space, the existence of additive inverse which is given as $\forall v\in V$, there exists a vector *-v* such that $v\oplus(-v)=0$.

Is the vector $0$ mentioned here is $[0$ $0$ $...$ $0]$ or it's used in reference to the additive identity vector (which need not to be $[0$ $0$ $...$ $0]$ always)??

Comment: It is a reference to the additive neutral element.

Comment: Its the identity element of the vector space. In coordinates it is always the zero vector.

Comment: There is no reason to assume the vectors look like tuples of coordinates. It is an axiom of vector spaces that they have a zero element. This is just the additive identity (in other words, vector spaces are required to be abelian groups)

Comment: @Wuestenfux So, Lets say $V=\{ x,y \}$ and the vector addition is defined such that $$x+x=x$$ $$x+y=y+x=y$$ $$y+y=y$$
Can we say here that identity element is $x$ and the additive inverse exists for each element (which is the element itself) as $$x+x=x,$$                    $$y+x=x$$

Comment: You have not defined an addition there, unless everything is $0$.

Comment: @ElliotG I didn't get your last comment!!

Comment: If $x+x=x$, then $x=0$. If also $y+x=x$, then $y=y+0=0$. So there is only one element in your vector space, which is zero.

Comment: @ElliotG I understood it now. So if the scalar multiplication is usual multiplication. Then *V* will be a vector space right?

Comment: What is $[0\ 0\ \ldots\ 0]$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I meant it a tuple whose all elements are 0, i,e. a zero vector

Comment: But nowhere in your question you state that the set $V$ is a set of tuples.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos consider $V=\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: *In that case*, yes. But, in general, a real vector space is not a subspace of $\Bbb R^n$. And you did not state in your question that that's the case here.